# OpenCV Python Running HAAR Cascade Detect in Threads

Tags: python, opencv, python-multithreading

I am trying to detect Vehicles using HAAR Cascade in a separate thread.

Here's some of my code:
Main Thread:

```
(isRead,cvImage)=cvCamSource.read()
lane1=Lane(cvCamSource,Lane.InflowLane)
print 'Blah Blah Blah!!'
```

Actual Worker Thread:

```
class Lane(Thread):
    def __init__(self,camSource,laneType):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.cvCam=camSource
        self.setLaneMask()


    def run(self):
        self.detectVehiclesCount()


    #Just update the Count
    def detectVehiclesCount(self):
        cascade=cv2.CascadeClassifier(self.cascadeFile)
        frameCount=0
        sumOfVehicleCounts=0
        noOfFramesAveraged=1000
        while frameCount<=noOfFramesAveraged:
            print frameCount
            #Read Image
            (isRead,cvImage)=self.cvCam.read()
            if isRead==True:
                frameCount+=1
                grayscaleImage=cv2.cvtColor(cvImage,cv.CV_BGR2GRAY)
                #Apply Lane Mask
                laneImage=np.bitwise_and(grayscaleImage,self.laneMask)
                rects = cascade.detectMultiScale(laneImage, scaleFactor=1.2, minNeighbors=4, minSize=(30,30), maxSize=(200,200))
                sumOfVehicleCounts+=len(rects)
            else:
                raise self.NoInputFromWebcam, "Can't Read From Webcam Source!"

        self.countOfVehicles=int(sumOfVehicleCounts/noOfFramesAveraged)


    #Set the Lane Mask
    def setLaneMask(self):
        (isRead,cvImage)=self.cvCam.read()

        if isRead:
            grayscaleImage=cv2.cvtColor(cvImage,cv.CV_BGR2GRAY)
            self.laneMask=self.extract_lane(grayscaleImage)
##            print 'Mask Image Created Successfully!'
        else:
            raise self.NoInputFromWebcam, "Can't Read From Webcam Source!"


    """
    Input grayscale cvImage
    Output cvImage of Mask
    'Mouse Click' to mark points, 'Space' to Preview and 'Enter' to Finalize Mask
    """
    def extract_lane(self, grayscaleImage):
        overlayImage=np.copy(grayscaleImage)
        cv2.namedWindow('preview')
        cPts=[[]]
        cv2.setMouseCallback('preview',self.on_mouse,(cPts,overlayImage,grayscaleImage))
        opacity=0.4
        while True:
            displayImage=cv2.addWeighted(overlayImage,opacity,grayscaleImage,1-opacity,0)
            cv2.imshow('preview',displayImage)
            keyPressed=cv2.waitKey(5)
            if keyPressed==27:
                break
            elif keyPressed==32:
                cv2.drawContours(overlayImage,np.array(cPts),0,255)
                maskImage=np.zeros_like(grayscaleImage)
                cv2.drawContours(maskImage,np.array(cPts),0,255,-1)
                extractedImage=np.bitwise_and(grayscaleImage,maskImage)
                cv2.imshow('extractedImage',extractedImage)
            elif keyPressed==13:
                break
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()

        return maskImage


    #Mouse Event Listener
    """Left Click to Draw, Right Click to Reset"""
    def on_mouse(self, event, x, y, flags,(cPts,overlayImage,resetImage)):
        if event==cv.CV_EVENT_LBUTTONUP:
            cPts[0].append([x,y])
            cv2.circle(overlayImage,(x,y),5,(255),-1)
            if len(cPts[0])>1:
                oldPoint=cPts[0][len(cPts[0])-2]
                cv2.line(overlayImage,(oldPoint[0],oldPoint[1]),(x,y),255)
        elif event==cv.CV_EVENT_RBUTTONUP:
            cPts[0]=[]
            overlayImage[:]=resetImage[:]
```

What happens is the Detect method blocks the main thread until it is finished and then 'Blah Blah Blah' prints.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you actually start the thread with ``lane1.start()`` before printing "blah..."? If not, then your main thread is still running (in the object constructor.)